# Order of sources when using strict-dynamic

Tags: content-security-policy

Documentation reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#strict-dynamic

The docs above state the backwards compatible way of working with 'strict-dynamic':

```
script-src 'unsafe-inline' https: 'nonce-abcdefg' 'strict-dynamic'
```

Is the difference with the example below that the 'nonce' value will take priority over 'strict-dynamic' in browsers that support CSP3 and therefore not apply the 'strict-dynamic' functionality:

```
script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-someNonce'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no priority. CSP level 1 didn't have nonces or strict-dynamic, level 2 did have nonces but not strict-dynamic. Level 1 is likely not relevant today. If a browser on CSP level 2, or partial level 3, sees 'strict-dynamic' it will simply ignore it and may show a console message that the keyword is unknown.